# Making a class friend itself

Tags: c++, friend

**EDIT:** It looks like I'm completely misinformed. Please close this thread. Gah.

For the record, the following compiles and works:

```
class ForeverAlone
{
private:
  int m_friends;
  HANDLE m_handle;

public:
  ForeverAlone()
  {
    m_handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ForeverAlone::SadThread, reinterpret_cast<void*>(this), 0, NULL);
  }

  ~ForeverAlone()
  {
    if (m_handle != NULL)
      CloseHandle(m_handle);
  }

protected:
  static unsigned long WINAPI SadThread(void* param)
  {
    ForeverAlone* thisObject = reinterpret_cast<ForeverAlone*>(param);

    // is there any way for me to access:
    thisObject->m_friends;
  }
};
```

Original question: I have a static protected thread method, which I pass an object to. Can I somehow make the class `friend` itself so I can access its private members?

Comment: Well yeah, because I have a *looooot* of members and I don't want to make accessors for all of them.

Comment: @Jonathan Lingle: Most modern IDEs make short work of generating accessors. Wouldn't that be a better option in terms of maintainability?

Comment: @JonathanLingle - I know it's been a while since I've done any serious C++ coding but if you can't access private members then how would copy constructors work? Then again I *could* have used accessors back then and forgotten about the pain.

Comment: A class is already a friend of itself. An object of class X can access any members of another object of type X with no special requirements.

Comment: Another method I have thought of: Copy everything from SadThread into a public non-static method called RunSadThread which will give me access to everything. Of course, this is most likely bad design.

I think I'll go with what @Asaph said and just make accessors.

Comment: @Loki Astari Not from a static method. EDIT: Or can I? (that's what I'm asking, I recall having trouble with this from a while ago)

Comment: Note: 1) `SadThread` is not static. 2) The third parameter to CreateThread() should be of type: [LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964928.aspx) which is not the same as a static member (its a C function).

Comment: Apparently I am a bad programmer. You are right. Hehe. I guess this just goes to show you should test something before asking about it.

Comment: @LokiAstari: a static class method works just fine wherever a C function can be used. It is perfectly valid, even common practice, to pass a static class method directly to `CreateThread()` and it works. I would even go as far as declaring its `param` parameter as `ForeverAlone*` to avoid the `thisObject` local variable, and then use `reinterpret_cast` in the `lpStartAddress` parameter of `CreateThread()` and not in the `lpParameter` parameter at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB: Absolutely wrong. It is common practice for beginners and I have seen it a lot. But everytime it happens at any company I have been in it gets rejected at code review time. It works by accident as the C++ API is not defined and just accidentally happens to be the same one being used for C functions. This is just a complete accident and non portable and should not be relied on. Though this is for Windows (and has worked and will probably continue to work) it is a bad habit to get into and will break one day for you when MS changes something or you move to another platform.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All class methods, static or not, are automatically "friends" of the class. Friend is used to allow external functions and classes access to a class. The class is always its own "friend".

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
extern "c"  DWORD  __stdcall CInterfaceSadThread(LPVOID lpThreadParameter);

class ForeverAlone
{
  private:
    int m_friends;
    HANDLE m_handle;

  public:
    ForeverAlone()
    {
      m_handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, 
                              &CInterfaceSadThread,
                              //
             // You may get arguments about using static_cast here
             // I still prefer reinterpret_cast as it makes it stick out
             // Thus I check it more carefully when I see it.
             // For this situation it works correctly
             // As casting to void* and back to the original are guaranteed.
                              reinterpret_cast<void*>(this), 
                              0, NULL);
    }

    ~ForeverAlone()
    {
      if (m_handle != NULL)
        CloseHandle(m_handle)
    }

  protected:
    friend DWORD  CInterfaceSadThread(LPVOID lpThreadParameter);
    DWORD WINAPI SadThread()
    {
      // Do Stuff here
      // Note: Just because you get here does not mean that the object is finished
      //       initializing. The parent thread may have been suspended after this
      //       one was created. Thus checking the state of member variables at this
      //       point is dangerous unless you can guarantee that construction has finished

      return result;
    }
};
```

Then in the callback just access your function;

```
extern "c" DWORD __stdcall  CInterfaceSadThread(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
{
    // Note: You can only cast back to ForeverAlone* so be carefull
    //       Hence I use reinterpret_cast as this forces me to double check.
    ForeverAlone*  alone = reinterpret_cast<ForeverAlone*>(lpThreadParameter);
    return alone->SadThread();
}
```

Comment: The C function wrapper is not necessary. Declare `SadThread()` as `static` and then pass it directly to `CreateThread()`. It works fine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB: Wrong. It is an accident that the ABI for static functions is the same as C ABI. It is totally bad practice to get into this habit.

Comment: Totally correct, but not what the OP was asking about; he just has a crummy sample program.